# Query for only part of objects of related_name (from ForeignKey)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have to models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,related_name='entries')
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
```

I would like to get **all** Blogs and inside each blog I would have that all entries where headline is 'bike'. 
So the output will be list of all Blogs and the blog.entries will have the filtered list of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(headline='bike')
blogs = Blog.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('entries', queryset=entries))
```

Comment: The related name is "entries", not "entry_set", and this is a quite convoluted (and not very efficient) way  to do a very simple thing, cf e4c5's answer (which is the obvious thing to do).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you one more time! But OP said he need all blogs. Doesn't `Blog.objects.filter(entries__headline='bike')` return only those with enries have "bike" in title?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this query

```
 Blog.objects.filter(entries__headline='bike')
```

It retrieves all the blogs that have an entry with the headline as bike ina  single query. So it's a lot easier on the server see Spanning [Multi Value Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Comment: This will filter Blogs, the thing I need Is to filter the entries related to blog, but have it still inside blog

Comment: "filter the entries related to blog" this is exactly what it does. Are you perhaps talking about displaying? Can you elaborate